# A Generic Error Occurred in GDI +. Saving a BMP image

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a BMP Image. I have to draw rectangles (more than 1) on it based on certain conditions. This is the code I'm using.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
    image.Save(strFileNameBMP);
    stream.Close();                       
}

try
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(strFileNameBMP);                    
    Pen black = new Pen(Color.Red, 4);                    

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(black, ix, iy, iw, ih);
        image.Save(strFileNameBMP);    // Line A                    
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Problem 1- If I try to save the final image as BMP, its shows "A generic error occurred in GDI+".

Problem 2- If I try to save it as a PNG in line A, it overwrites the image and I can see on 1 rectangle. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You're trying to save the file which is already open by `Image.FromFile`. Save it in different location or take a copy of image(in memory or filesystem), edit, then save

Comment: But it should be open for saving. Right? If I take a copy of image and draw rectangle to it, it'll overwrite the file.